# Apply a method if condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a built-in method to do this :

```
value = value.is_a?(String) ? value.to_i : value
```

in form of:

```
value.apply_if!(:to_i, value.is_a?(String))
```

?

Comment: Are you sure? What is your question?

Comment: You can't change an object's class. It's impossible for a `String` to become an `Integer`.

Comment: for compact and clean code. value.try(:to_i) is a cool feature, and I find similar feature for custom condition.

Comment: just an example @Stefan

Comment: @barbacan to put it another way: you can't replace (such) an assignment with a method call.

Comment: Ok for assignement. More explicit example, without class consideration , would be
    value.apply_if(:downcase, value.length < 10)

Comment: @barbacan `value.downcase! if value.length < 10` is even shorter :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no builtin method for this, but you can write it more concisely using [expression modifiers](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless):

```
value = value.to_i if value.is_a?(String)
```

Comment: finally, no better solution :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ensure that `value` is an `Integer`, you can call `to_i` regardless of its type:

```
value = value.to_i

123.to_i    #=> 123
"123".to_i  #=> 123
"foo".to_i  #=> 0
```

You can also use [`Kernel::Integer`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) which does more strict checking:

```
value = Integer(value)

Integer(123)    #=> 123
Integer("123")  #=> 123
Integer("foo")  #=> ArgumentError
```

Otherwise I'd prefer duck typing over type checking:

```
value = value.some_method if value.respond_to?(:some_method)
```

In Rails you could use:

```
value = value.try(:some_method) || value
```

Comment: Missing element in this answser : I want to ensure that value is an Integer if a condition is true

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately, this isn't possible. You want to change the binding of a variable by calling a method on the variable, but that's not possible: variables aren't objects, you cannot call methods on them.

Comment: This kind of thing would be possible in Ioke or Seph, for example. (At least I think it would.)